# Configuring PHP on Solaris 10 64-bit

Tags: php, solaris, 64-bit, solaris-10

We are currently running PHP 5.2.13 on a Solaris 10 server. I need to enable some additional features so I went to run the configure script but I'm getting some errors.

I did an 'export CFLAGS="-m64"' to make sure GCC compiled in 64-bit mode, but it looks like I don't have a 64-bit version of libiconv.so. I've tried running the script with '--without-iconv' but no dice. Here's the end of my config.log:

```
configure:20017: checking for strftime
configure:20471: checking whether to enable LIBXML support
configure:20519: checking libxml2 install dir
configure:20548: checking for xml2-config path
configure:20706: checking whether libxml build works
configure:20733: gcc -o conftest -m64  -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS  -R/usr/ucblib -L/usr/ucblib -R/usr/local/lib/../lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/3.4.6 -L/usr/local/lib/../lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/3.4.6 -R/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib conftest.c 

     -lrt -lresolv -lm -lnsl -lsocket  -lgcc -lxml2 -lz -liconv -lm -lsocket -lnsl 1>&5
ld: fatal: file /usr/local/lib/libiconv.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
ld: fatal: File processing errors. No output written to conftest
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
configure: failed program was:
#line 20722 "configure"
#include "confdefs.h"


    char xmlInitParser();
    int main() {
      xmlInitParser();
      return 0;
    }
```

Is there any way around this? I've been banging my head against this since yesterday. If it helps, here's my configure line:

```
./configure  --prefix=/usr/local/php --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php/lib --with-libxml-dir=/usr/local --with-zlib=/usr/local --with-xpm-dir=/usr/local --with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql --with-mysqli=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --without-pgsql --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/lib --with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/lib --with-gd=/usr/local --enable-mbstring --enable-exif --enable-force-cgi-redirect --enable-sockets --with-png-dir=/usr/local/lib --with-curl=/usr/local --with-ldap=/usr/local --with-openssl=/usr/local/ssl --with-gettext --with-pcre-dir=/usr/local --with-freetype-dir=/usr/local --with-mssql=/usr/local/freetds --with-readline --enable-soap
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has always been my biggest hassle with Solaris. Essentially if you're going to compile something, you need to make sure ALL of the following are correct:

- `CFLAGS` / `CXXFLAGS` (for C++)
- `LDFLAGS` (for the linker)
- Possibly `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Make sure any include dirs (specified with `-I`) and library dirs (`-R` and/or `-L`) match the architecture you're building for. For Solaris, `gcc` often looks at `/usr/lib`, `/usr/sfw/lib` etc first, but if you want 64-bit then you need to compile against `/usr/lib/64`, `/usr/sfw/lib/64`, etc - specifying `gcc -m64` isn't enough for it to do this.

You can verify the ISA of the existing iconv library using `ldd` and `file`. If you compiled libiconv yourself, you'll need to recompile it, otherwise find another binary source or... recompile it :-)

Comment: The existing iconv library is definitely 32-bit. It was on the server already, so I don't know how to compile it for 64-bit. The crazy thing is, PHP is already installed on this server so I have no idea how they got it to work last time...

Comment: The existing PHP must be 32-bit then. Have you checked with `ldd` and `file`? If you want your PHP to be 64-bit then you'll have to recompile everything it depends on too. I ended up writing a system based on FreeBSD ports to make compiling on Solaris less painful. http://www.netinertia.co.uk/hg/solports/

Answer (score 2):

In my case, to compile PHP 5.4.7 I had to add the PHP_LDFLAGS env var as well:
LDFLAGS="-L/opt/selfcompiled/libs/64 -L/lib/64 -L/usr/sfw/lib/64 -m64"
PHP_LDFLAGS=$LDFLAGS